# Creating a new Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I'm beginner at Oracle so I need a little help. I created a Procedure:

```
NAMEPROCEDURE
    (
    p_CodAFD IN VARCHAR2
   ,p_CodGEN IN VARCHAR2
   ,p_cursor OUT sys_refcursor
  )
AS
BEGIN


  OPEN p_cursor FOR
  SELECT 
    to_number(err.id) AS D_ERRORAFD 
  , err.DESCRIPCION AS D_DESCRIPAFD
  FROM errores err
  WHERE (p_CodAFD IS NULL OR err.ID = p_CodAFD)  
 UNION
  SELECT
     to_number(t.CODERRORAFD) AS D_ERRORAFD
    ,to_number(t.CODERRORGENESIS) AS D_ERRORGEN
    ,t.DESCRIPCIONERROR  AS D_DESCRIPGEN
    FROM TRADUCTORAGENESISAFD t
    WHERE t.CODERRORAFD = p_CodAFD
    AND (p_CodGEN IS NULL OR t.CODERRORGENESIS = p_CodGEN)
  order by D_ERRORAFD DESC;

END;
/
```

I think you know what it supose to do. But it doesn't work and the first `SELECT` statement it's ignored. But I'll tell you.

*ERRORES TABLE*

```
CODE-AFD   DESCRIPTION-AFD
5466       //SOMEWORDS1
...        ...
```

*TRADUCTORGENESISAFD TABLE*

```
CODE-AFD   CODE-GEN  DESCRIPTION-GEN
5466       5767      //SOMEWORDS2
...        ...       ...
...        ...       ...
```

What I'd like to get

```
CODE-AFD    DESCRIPTION-AFD    COD-GEN    DESCRIPTION-GEN
5466        //SOMEWORDS1       5767       //SOMEWORDS2
...         ...                ...        ...
```

Do I need to use a inner join. If it's like that way. How?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the first `SELECT` is ignored?  Are you getting an error that a statement is ignored?  Is your query not returning the results you expect?  What does your data look like, what are the values of the parameters being passed in?  What are the results that you are actually getting?

Comment: @JustinCave Done, I just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, it appears you need to use a join:

```
SELECT to_number(e.ID) AS "CODE-AFD",
       e.DESCRIPCION AS "DESCRIPTION-AFD",
       t.CODERRORGENESIS AS "CODE-GEN",
       t.DESCRIPCIONERROR AS "DESCRIPTION-GEN"
  FROM errores e
  INNER JOIN TRADUCTORAGENESISAFD t
    ON t.CODERRORAFD = e.ID
  WHERE e.ID = NVL(p_CodAFDm e.ID)
  order by t.CODERRORAFD DESC
```

Best of luck.